# How to use Shinycssloaders from beginning of fileInput loading?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity, shinyjs

I'm deploying an app with Shiny and I need to load a file, for that I'm using the fileInput function although I don't necessarily have to use this function, and I want to use a function from the shinycssloaders package while the file is being loaded. My problem is that I want to get a spinner immediately after selecting a file, but this spinner starts showing up some time after I've selected the file especially when the file is big.

My code is the following:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("data", label = "Select a file")),
    mainPanel(
      shinycssloaders::withSpinner(DT::DTOutput("table"), caption = "Loading...")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=300*1024^5)
  data <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$data, 'Please, select a file to start'))  
    shinycssloaders::showPageSpinner(caption = "Loading data...")
    datos <- vroom::vroom(input$data$datapath, delim = ",")
    shinycssloaders::hidePageSpinner()
    return(datos)
  })
  output$table <- DT::renderDT(
    dplyr::sample_n(data(), 100),
    filter = "top",
    options = list(pageLength = 10,
                   extensions = 'Responsive')
  )
}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any solution is welcome, thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried using the [waiter](https://waiter.john-coene.com/#/) package? In my experience, `shinycssloaders` work fine for outputs, but `waiter` is better suited for showing loading messages while doing computation or loading big files.

Comment: @BastiánOleaHerrera Are you sure? I took a look at the doc and didn't see anything regarding uploading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **shinybusy** package to do the following. With a bit of JavaScript, send a Shiny event when the file input is used (the `change` event). Then in the Shiny app you can use a manual spinner from **shinybusy**, you trigger it when the Shiny event is fired and you hide it at the end of your reactive conductor. Here is a small demo (I would use a larger spinner).

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinybusy)
library(vroom)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=300*1024^5)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#data').on('change', function() {
    Shiny.setInputValue('upload', true, {priority: 'event'});
  });
});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  
  use_busy_spinner(
    spin = "semipolar",
    color = "#112446",
    position = "full-page",
    margins = c(10, 10),
    height = "150px",
    width = "150px"
  ),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("data", label = "Select a file")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  data <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$data, 'Please, select a file to start'))  
    datos <- vroom::vroom(input$data$datapath, delim = ",")
    hide_spinner()
    return(datos)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT(
    dplyr::sample_n(data(), 100),
    filter = "top",
    options = list(pageLength = 10)
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$upload, {
    show_spinner()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]